# Gnuplot script creating a .tex file - symbols in legend don't work

Tags: gnuplot

I have such code named `file.gpl`:

```
set xlabel "dl"
set ylabel "ten"
set pointsize 0.5
set key left samplen 0.5

set term epslatex color standalone

set out 'plot.tex'

p [800:1000] 'Data' u 1:($2/1) title "$328,20^{\circ}C$"

unset out
```

and the additional one named `gnuplot.cfg`:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

and the `\circ` symbol doesn't work. I tried gnuplot coding \260 but it also failed. I don't get it... Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get `"file.gpl", line 10: warning: Cannot find or open file "Data"`; can you add a small data file?

Comment: Ok, I've got it. Line 10 should look like this:

p [800:1000] 'Data' u 1:($2/1) title '280,12 $^\circ$C',

:)

Comment: jap, its an escaping issue. either use single apostrophes ('  ')  or double (" ") and escaping ("\\command")